# simple harmonic oscillator functions space and real plane

Tags: linear-algebra

the functions that satisfy the simple harmonic oscillator equation
$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x  }{\mathrm{d} t^2}=-\omega _{0}^2x$
constitute a linear space .

is this linear space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: Can you find a basis?

Comment: i'm not sure but i think $\{x'(0) , x(0)\}$  is a basis. @MatthewLeingang

Comment: Not exactly.   If the linear space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, you should be able to find functions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ which are linearly independent and such that any solution to the equation is a linear combination of these two.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang is $\{cos(\omega t), sin(\omega t)\}$ the answer?

Comment: That is a basis, yes.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks professor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit advanced for you now, but eventually you may study linear systems of differential equations.  They take the form $\mathbf{y}'(t) = A \mathbf{y}(t)$, where $\mathbf{y}(t)$ is a (column) vector of $n$ functions of $t$, and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

Your equation is one of these, because you can let $y_1(t) = x(t)$ and $y_2(t) = x'(t)$.  Then $y_1' = y_2$ and $y_2' = -\omega_0^2 y_1$.  That is,
$$
    \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}'
   =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega_0^2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution space of a linear system of $n$ differential equations has dimension $n$.